# Hibernate LeftOuter join HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql

This is my `left join` hql query. After executing this code i am getting list size. But unable cast object to respective pojo class.

```
Query query=session.createQuery("from BwClientdetails client left join client.bwClientAllocations");

System.out.println(">>>"+query.list().size());
List<BwClientdetails> list=query.list();
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
   BwClientdetails bc=list.get(i);
   System.out.println(bc.getClientid());
}
```

I am getting below error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to org.bluewhale.model.BwClientdetails
        at testapplication.Main.getClients(Main.java:364)
        at testapplication.Main.main(Main.java:54)
```

Answer (score 2):

By not specifing a Select case, the result of your query is an Array of BwClientdetails, bwClientAllocations.
Adding `Select client` in front of the query should solve your problem

```
Select client from  BwClientdetails  client left  join client.bwClientAllocations
```

or replacing your for by

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
   BwClientdetails bc=list.get(i)[0];
   System.out.println(bc.getClientid());
}
```

It's a best practice to alway specify a where clause, it is even part of the JPA spec