# Not able to get the row if there is null value in one column hibernate hql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm, hql

I'm having difficulties in search operation. If there is any `null` value in a column of one row then that row is not coming. I tried using `is not null` in `hql`, but I'm not able get the values. I have written `hql` query like this. It is returning nothing. I'm not able to understand how it is working. Please tell me the solution for this one. I'm using `mysql`.

```
session.createQuery("FROM Employee e WHERE (e.company is not null and e.company.name = :p1) or e.name = :p1").setParameter("p1", str)
```

My `@Entity` classes are these:

```
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private float salary;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Company company;
```

[image: data of <code>Employee</code> in the Database]

```
@Entity
public class Company implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String Location;
```

[image: data of the <code>Company</code> table]

Comment: For future readers. When you use left join you have to use select clause like`select e from Employee e`..https://stackoverflow.com/q/5922768/4238176

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
session.createQuery("FROM Employee e left join e.company c WHERE c.name = :p1 or e.name = :p1").setParameter("p1", "uday11")
```

When you use `e.company` in your query it is translated to `inner join`, that's why it is not working as expected.

Comment: ..Thank u so much its working but the result is not casting into Employee Object.May be its returning.Object type.

Comment: How are you calling it? This should work: `List<Employee> result = (List<Employee>)session.createQuery(<the query>).setParameter(...).list();`

Comment: i'm doing like this `List<Employee> e =  session.createQuery("FROM Employee e left join e.company c WHERE c.name = :p1 or e.name = :p1").setParameter("p1", "uday11").list();`

Comment: You need to cast the result to `List<Employee>` because `query.list()` returns a generic list.

Comment: Casted the result but it still giving class cast exception.

Comment: Can you post the exception?

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to Employee
 at EmployeeDao.main(EmployeeDao.java:73)
Java Result: 1`

Comment: Strange. Better to post a new question with all the necessary code and details.

Comment: Are you sure...???  Why because i'm Newbie and i'm not sure about everything..I'm little afraid about this stackoverflow down voting system.and right now i don't have permission to post new Question.Thank u so much for helping..You people are so much Helpful..

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce the exception you are getting. I have the same code in many places and it simply works, so it must be something specific to your setup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72770/discussion-between-predrag-maric-and-udaybhaskar).